# PHP Class - How to connect to the database only once

Tags: php, class, load

I tried to do a simple SQL class.
There is just one problem:

```
function __classDBREAD($table, $where, $value, $back)
{
    $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','XXXX','XXXXXX');
    mysql_select_db('XXXX', $link);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where = '$value' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row[$back];
    mysql_close($link);
}
```

Now, how can I connect to the SQL only once and add functions like "dbUpdate", "dbInsert" and "dbRead" without connecting to the database every time?

The same for the teamspeak connection.

Here an example:

```
require_once                      ("lib/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");
    $ts3_VirtualServer              = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://XXXXX:XXXX@127.0.0.1:10011/?server_port=XXXX");
    $__varTeamspeakClients          = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientList();
    $__intTeamspeakClientsOnline    = $ts3_VirtualServer["virtualserver_clientsonline"] - 1;
    $ts3_VirtualServer->request('clientupdate client_nickname='.$this->__classRndString(8));
```

The same problem. How to define the connection only once, when I include the Class to the page?

Comment: for one thing you can't mix `mysqli_` being `mysqli_close($link);` with your `mysql_` functions.

Comment: and don't `mysqli_close($link);` so you don't have to open it again

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I fixed it.

Comment: If you are familiar with OOP, check out a `singleton` pattern. See if that interests you *(not to be used too heavily if implemented though...)*.

Comment: Well, I'd like to keep this. So, is there any way to connect to the DB outside of the function and call to update/select/insert it in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not be using the mysql_* functions at all. They're deprecated and dangerous to use. Buth hypthetically, you could use globals.

Define your connection outside of the function (in the global scope) then use `global` to give your function acces to it. Now all you have to do is include that one "global" line in all your functions that need it.

```
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','XXXX','XXXXXX');

function __classDBREAD($table, $where, $value, $back)
{
    global $link;
    mysql_select_db('XXXX', $link);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where = '$value' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row[$back];
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

**EDIT...**

I didn't read this too closely. I see you're working on a class, so globals is not the best option. Consider this..

```
class mydbclassthing {
    private $conn;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','XXXX','XXXXXX');
    }

    function __classDBREAD($table, $where, $value, $back)
    {
        $link = $this->con;
        mysql_select_db('XXXX', $link);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where = '$value' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row[$back];
        mysql_close($link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, yeah i suppose it would if you wanted to re-write the library. I'm not familiar with that library so I can't tell you the est way to handle that.

Comment: Would I use this as on top of the file (out of the functions) and link it to it, it should work. 
By this way, can I use require_once  on top of the file, right?

Comment: @ZackDaniPoladro `require_once` will work, but check my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Since everyone is tossing their OOP into the ring *(NOTE: I am going to do PDO because I know it better, but the principle is the same, just substitute the connection)*:

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnection
    {
        # Create a singleton to store the connection for reuse
        private static $singleton,
                       $con;
        # save connection to singleton and return itself (the full object)
        public function __construct()
           {
                # If your singleton is not set
                if(!isset(self::$singleton))
                    # assign it this class
                    self::$singleton = $this;
                # return this class
                return self::$singleton;
           }
        # This is a connection method because your __construct
        # is not able to return the $pdo connection
        public function connection($host='hostname',$username='username',$password='password',$database='database')
            {
                # In the connection, you can assign the PDO to a static
                # variable to send it back if it's already set
                if(self::$con instanceof \PDO)
                    return self::$con;
                # If not already a PDO connection, try and make one
                try {
                        # PDO settings you can apply at connection time
                        $opts = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false);
                        # Assign your PDO Conneciton here.
                        self::$con =  new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database}",$username,$password,$opts);
                        # Return the connection
                        return self::$con;
                    }
                catch (PDOException $e){
                        exit('Database error');
                    }   
            }
    }
```

You can use it anywhere, in and outside of your functions, classes, you name it. It will return the same connection every time. If you use `spl_autoload_register()` with an autoload function you will be all set and not even have to explicitly use the `require_once()` every time!

```
<?php
require_once('class.DatabaseConnection.php');
// Instantiate connection class
$pdo = new DatabaseConnection();
// Assign the connection to $con (or whatever variable you like)
$con = $pdo->connection();
```

*One note of caution, `singleton` patterns are generally used minimally. Often it is better to use `new Objects()` without assigning it a `singleton`. I personally like the `singleton` for this use however.*

---

---

**SIMPLE DEMONSTRATION - Consider this scenario:**

```
<?php
// Here is an example of the singlton with an echo
// which shows that the class is returning itself
// like a global
class DatabaseConnection
    {
        private static $singleton;
        public function __construct()
           {
                // If your singleton is not set
                if(!isset(self::$singleton)) {
                        echo 'NEW Object'.PHP_EOL;
                        // assign it this class
                        self::$singleton = $this;
                    }
                else
                    echo 'SAME Object'.PHP_EOL;
                // return this class
                return self::$singleton;
           }
    }

function ReturnConnection()
    {
        return new DatabaseConnection();
    }

class TestClass
    {
        public  function __construct()
            {
                new DatabaseConnection();
            }
    }

function query($sql=false)
    {
        return ReturnConnection();
    }

// The connection class wrapped in a function 
$a = ReturnConnection();
// The function nested inside a class
$b = new TestClass();
// The function nested inside another function
$c = query();
```

The above uses of the `singleton` will produce:

```
NEW Object
SAME Object
SAME Object
```

Comment: Why are you `return self::$singleton;`-ing in the `__constructor()` function. Constructor functions in PHP always return void, so this is being ignored... A result of this is that each time you use the `new` keyword with the `DatabaseConnection` class, you're getting a new instance of it... The fact that you're using a separate function is what makes this act like a singleton, but it really isn't one. Use the `spl_object_id` function, and you'll see that they're all actually different `DatabaseConnection` objects.

Comment: I think the question is why is anyone referencing this 7 years on and secondly why has no one mentioned this in all that time! lol. Yes, construct returns void.

Answer (score 0):

As the PHP documentation says about Persistent Database Connections (http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php):

> an instance of the PHP interpreter is created and destroyed for every
>   page request (for a PHP page) to your web server. Because it is
>   destroyed after every request, any resources that it acquires (such as
>   a link to an SQL database server) are closed when it is destroyed. In
>   this case, you do not gain anything from trying to use persistent
>   connections -- they simply don't persist.

If what you want is to re-use code more eficiently, doing it the OOP way is the key.

I might think about a better solution later, but what I'd do is to use class members to store links to SQL, so they don't have to be created everytime:

```
class MySQL {

    protected $mysql_link;
    protected $server = '127.0.0.1'; //and so on...

    public function __construct() {
       $this->link = mysql_connect($this->server,$this->user,$this->password);
       mysql_select_db($this->selected_db, $this->link);
       mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    }

    public function link() {
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function close() {
        return mysql_close($this->link);
    }

}
```

Now, using OOP in the rest of your application (something like dependency injection) would be awesome, but if not, anyway, you can always instantiate the class you're creating and even store that object in a $_SESSION variable.

Using the $object->link() will always return that instance's link, instead of creating new ones everytime you need to execute any Query,