# DB Conn Function

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying something pretty simple but doesn't seem to work. I want to create a function called db_conn() so I can call it to open a mysql database instead of making a new call every time I need to do so. Here is the function:

```
    /**************************************
    Open Database Connection Function.
    ***************************************/
    /* Database Connection Settings */
    $_SESSION['servername']     = "localhost";
    $_SESSION['mysql_username'] = "abc123";
    $_SESSION['mysql_password'] = "mypass";
    $_SESSION['dbname']         = "dbname";


    function db_conn() {

        $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['mysql_username'], $_SESSION['mysql_password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

        // Test if connection succeeded
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . 
                 mysqli_connect_error() . 
                 " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
            );
        }
    }
```

A sample call to the function and echo out data:

```
      <?php
        db_conn();

        $sql = "SELECT id, region FROM tbl_region;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                echo '<td width="1"><label for="delete">
  <input type="radio" name="region" id="region" value="'.$row["id"].'">
</label></td>';

                echo '<td align="left" valign="top"><p>'.$row["region"].'</p></td></tr>';
            }
        }

      ?>
```

When I test the page it stops at the code above and doesn't display any errors. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with the db_conn function?

Comment: What does error_reporting shows in phpinfo?

Answer (score 2):

`$conn` is only available inside your function `db_conn()`, it is beyond scope outside.

If you enable error reporting and display them you will notice the error 100%.

Although there are better ways of doing this but if you want to do it as an exercise, you can make your function return the connection resource to caller.

```
$conn=db_conn();
```

And your function can return it

```
function db_conn() {
// body
return $conn;
}
```

Comment: Okay so does this mean it will not work? Or if it could would what I need to do then? Or do I need to make conn a Session variable so the page can see the value of it?

Comment: You say there are better ways I am new to PHP could you tell me a better way please so I am doing it correctly? I thought this was the best way. Thanks again!

Comment: One design pattern is called dependency injection, you can go through it here https://codeinphp.github.io/post/dependency-injection-in-php/

Comment: If you're new to PHP i think this one will really help you a lot to have a strong base https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954301/php-class-how-to-connect-to-the-database-only-once

Comment: Hanky Panky I read your article above but finding a little difficult to understand. So I hopped on youtube to take a peak this tutorial would this be a good understand of what dependency inject is?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKDxVx1nO2w

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
$conn = '';
function db_conn() {
    global $conn;
    $conn = new mysqli... //the rest of your code here
}
```